# Handle state when generate multiple forms on a button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create something where a user can add multiple addresses, with a maximum of 3 and the default one which can't be removed.

For this example, an address is just a street name and city.

What i'm struggling to figure out is how I can handle the state and the form input fields for this scenario.

I could have 3 separate states for each address and just target the state values in the forms that way, but I'd like to know if you guys have a cleaner approach to doing something like this.

And once the form is submitted, I would want an array of these addresses as they form part of another object in my use case.

Here's the React code

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [addressCount, setAddressCount] = useState(1);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState([]);

  const handleAddressChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // handle address state
  };

  const addAddress = () => {
    if (addressCount == 3) {
      alert("you cannot more than 3 addresses");
      return;
    }
    setAddressCount(addressCount + 1);
  };

  const removeAddress = () => {
    if (addressCount == 1) {
      alert("You cannot remove this address");
      return;
    }
    setAddressCount(addressCount - 1);
  };

  const AddressDiv = (index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} className="address-section">
        <div className="mb-2">
          <label>Street name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter street name"
            name="streetName"
            onChange={handleAddressChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mb-2">
          <label>City</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter city name"
            name="streetName"
            onChange={handleAddressChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="add-another-address-section mt-3 mb-4">
          <button type="button" onClick={addAddress}>
            + Add another
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={removeAddress}>
            - Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      DIV COUNT {addressCount}
      <AddressDiv />
      {Array.from({ length: addressCount - 1 }, (_, index) => {
        return <div style={{ margin: "2rem" }}>{AddressDiv(index)}</div>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here's a CodeSandbox link of what It roughly looks like.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/generate-div-8hknk3?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A63%2C26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addressCount` is redundant state and should be removed as it can always be computed from `address` (namely, `address.length`). The code can be simplified like so:

```
export default function App() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState([{ id: 0 }]);
  const id = useRef(0);
  const addAddress = (insertAfter) => {
    if (address.length === 3) alert('you cannot more than 3 addresses');
    else
      setAddress(address.toSpliced(insertAfter + 1, 0, { id: ++id.current }));
  };
  const removeAddress = (index) => {
    if (index === 0) alert('You cannot remove this address');
    else setAddress(address.toSpliced(index, 1));
  };
  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    setAddress(
      address.map((o, i) =>
        i !== index ? o : { ...o, [event.target.name]: event.target.value }
      )
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      DIV COUNT {address.length}
      {address.map((o, index) => (
        <div key={o.id} className="address-section">
          <div className="mb-2">
            <label>Street name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter street name"
              name="streetName"
              value={o.streetName}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-2">
            <label>City</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter city name"
              name="cityName"
              value={o.cityName}
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="add-another-address-section mt-3 mb-4">
            <button type="button" onClick={() => addAddress(index)}>
              + Add another
            </button>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => removeAddress(index)}>
              - Remove
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot. That works. Just need to understand what's all going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modified example of Unmitigated's response.

- Move address section to its own component
- Utilize callbacks with dependencies
- Add additional Bootstrap classes

```js
const { useCallback, useRef, useState } = React;

const ADDRESS_COUNT_MAX = 3;

const AddressSection = ({
  address: { id, cityName, streetName },
  index,
  addAddress,
  removeAddress,
  handleChange
}) => {
  return (
    <div key={id} className="address-section">
      <div className="form-group row">
        <label className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Street name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter street name"
            name="streetName"
            value={streetName}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group row">
        <label className="col-sm-3 col-form-label">City</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter city name"
            name="cityName"
            value={cityName}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, index)}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="add-another-address-section mt-3 mb-4">
        <button
            type="button"
            className="btn btn-primary"
            onClick={() => addAddress(index)}>
          + Add another
        </button>
        {index > 0
          ? (
            <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-danger"
                onClick={() => removeAddress(index)}>
          - Remove
        </button>
          ) : null}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [addressList, setAddressList] = useState([{ id: 0 }]);

  const id = useRef(0);

  const addAddress = useCallback((insertAfter) => {
    if (addressList.length === ADDRESS_COUNT_MAX) {
      alert(`You cannot more than ${ADDRESS_COUNT_MAX} address(es)`);
    } else {
      setAddressList(currentAddressList =>
        currentAddressList.toSpliced(insertAfter + 1, 0, { id: ++id.current }));
    }
  }, [addressList]);

  const removeAddress = useCallback((index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      alert("You cannot remove this address");
    } else setAddressList(currentAddressList => currentAddressList.toSpliced(index, 1));
  }, []);

  const handleChange = useCallback(({ target: { name, value } }, index) => {
    setAddressList(currentAddressList =>
      currentAddressList.map((address, currentIndex) => currentIndex !== index
        ? address
        : { ...address, [name]: value }));
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <form>
          {addressList.map((address, index) => (
            <AddressSection
              key={index}
              address={address}
              index={index}
              addAddress={addAddress}
              removeAddress={removeAddress}
              handleChange={handleChange}
            />
          ))}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This will come in handy as well.